# Как создать и запушить папки в github

Tags: git

Необходимо разбить файлы с кодом по папкам(src и прочее). Как создать папку(тут скорее всего как обычно создается папка, может я чего то не знаю) и запушить эту папку в свой репозиторий?

Comment: всё как обычно. создаете папку. потом `git add .` или `git add ПАПКА`, `git commit -m "message"`, `git push origin BRANCH`

Answer (score 2):

Для того что бы создать git репозиторий вам необходимо скачать Git click, установить. Если вы пользуетесь Windows откройте папку вашего репозитория, ПКМ -> git bash here

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого инициализируйте репозиторий `git init`. Репозиторий создан. Добавьте в него файлы. Воспользуйтесь git add . - для всех файлов или добавляйте их по одному `git add filename.test` - добавит файл "filename.test". 
Далее можно воспользоваться командой `git status`. Ваши файлы должны быть написаны зеленым цветом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перед коммитом рекомендуется указать ваше имя и email

```
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

Если вы добавили все файлы и готовы сделать коммит - прописываем 
`git commit -m"описание коммита in english"`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ваш репозиторий создан и наполнен данными, теперь его можно запушить, создаём аккаунт на гитхабе, после создания и настройке вам выдадут ссылку для push-а репозитория. Выполняем команду `git remote add name https://github.com/freQuensy23-coder/MD_to_LATEX`
Где вместо ссылки вставляем свою, name - имя репозитория. Можно придумать что то оригинальное, можно оставить это, но у вас не должно быть 2-х одинаковых имён у разных репозиториев.

После этого отправляем пуш. Пользуемcя командой 'git push name branch` Где branch - имя ветки. По умолчанию - master - основная. По выполнению команды git сообщит об удачном пуше

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]